# How to add TextView to the top of a custom keyboard

Tags: android

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ntI0Q.jpg)

```
@Override public View onCreateInputView() {
    kv = (KeyboardView)getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.keyboard, null);
    keyboard = new Keyboard(this, R.xml.qwerty); kv.setKeyboard(keyboard);
    UserDictionary.Words.addWord(this, "MadeUpWord", 10, "Mad", Locale.getDefault());
    kv.setOnKeyboardActionListener(this);
    return kv;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can follow below link to make custom keyboard:

[Create a Custom Keyboard on Android](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-custom-keyboard-on-android--cms-22615)

Create a file named res/layout/keyboard.xml and replace its contents with the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<android.inputmethodservice.KeyboardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/keyboard"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:keyPreviewLayout ="@layout/preview"
/>
```

The keyPreviewLayout is the layout of the short-lived pop-up that shows up whenever a key on the keyboard is pressed. It contains a single TextView. Create a file named res/layout/preview.xml and add the following to it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="#ffff00"   
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    >    
</TextView>
```

Comment: thank you for your reply but i already done this now i need to add textview on the top of the keyboard that shows text suggestions...